# How do I bind a new footer1.xml to a word document?

Tags: java, docx4j

I have an already existing word document that has a footer with text. I've found the relationship part that I want to replace and have footer part that I want to replace it with.

From what I understand I should be able to just use .addTargetPart(Part foo) to overwrite the old footer1.xml, with my new footer that I've created but it seems to be doing nothing.

```
FooterPart footerPart = ((FooterPart) relationshipPart.getPart(relationship));
footerPart.setJaxbElement((Ftr) footerObj);
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(footerPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to replace the contents of the existing part:

```
FooterPart footerPart = ((FooterPart) relationshipPart.getPart(relationship));
footerPart.setJaxbElement((Ftr) footerObj);
```

There is no need to add the part again.

But you are correct, calling addTargetPart like you have will OVERWRITE_IF_NAME_EXISTS:

```
public Relationship addTargetPart(Part targetpart) throws InvalidFormatException {
    return this.addTargetPart(targetpart, AddPartBehaviour.OVERWRITE_IF_NAME_EXISTS, null);
}
```

So I suspect the footer you are replacing is not the one you are seeing in the docx.  Possibly it has a first page footer?  Unzip it and have a look.  Or run the HeaderFooterList sample code.